# Tener un boton de stop opencv donde cierre el proceso cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv

Hola amigos tengo una duda con respecto a opencv si tengo codigo que inicia una camara y la transmision lo realizaria de la siguiente forma `cv2.VideoCapture(0).read()` todo claro hasta ese punto, pero ahora quiero dale un stop a esa transmision de video. ejemplo: tengo una app que con un boton inicia la transmision de video, pero quiero tener un boton que finalice esa transmision es decir cierre ese proceso pero que si de doy nuevamente a iniciar vuelva y arranque el proceso puedo lograr hacerlo, gracias por las aclaraciones.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código porque sin contexto de cómo lo haces va a ser difícil darte una respuesta

Comment: @DannyTalent te entiendo pero mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de así como se inicia poder tener un stop es decir alguna función original de opencv

Comment: Por eso te digo que deberías poner el código... Bueno imagino que tienes el `read()` en alguna especie de loop, simplemente sería hacer un botón que te saque de ese loop para que no se siga ejecutando la lectura, no?

Comment: Y si quieres cerrarlo definitivamente sería `[tuobjetovideocapture].release()` y `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: ok vale amigo voy a leer mas sobre esos dos funciones, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defenir una función dónde ejecute el release() y El cv2.destroyAllWindows() de esta forma lo solucione gracias por las ayudas